# Enabling RNDIS Host interface

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I have a PC running Ubuntu 16.04.1. The kernel version is 4.13.0-38-generic. I am trying to establish RNDIS USB ethernet host connectivity with busybox, which runs as RNDIS device and tested working over a Windows RNDIS HOST.

My Ubuntu machine won't recognize the RNDIS device at all.

`CONFIG_USB_NET_RNDIS_HOST=m` is seen set in kernel config.

I do see the kernel module (`rndis_host.ko`) under `/lib/modules/4.13.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/`.

I am not able to insert the module.

Comment: Please add the output of trying to insert the module.

Comment: insmod: ERROR: could not insert module rndis_host.ko: Unknown symbol in module

and dmesg output: 
[255849.418513] rndis_host: Unknown symbol usbnet_generic_cdc_bind (err 0)
[255849.418532] rndis_host: Unknown symbol usbnet_cdc_unbind (err 0)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$ modprobe rndis_host` to automatically resolve dependenies.

I met this problem too.

According error msg (`Unknown symbol usbnet_generic_cdc_bind`) from `dmesg`, I guess `rndis_host.ko` depends on other kernel modules.

Before `modprobe rndis_host`:

```shell
$ lsmod | grep usb
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             524288  28 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   122880  2 usbhid,hid_generic
```

After `modprobe rndis_host`:

```
$ lsmod | grep "usb"
usbnet                 45056  2 rndis_host,cdc_ether
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             524288  28 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   122880  2 usbhid,hid_generic
```